# What are some good strategies playing on Chaffee?

Tags: world-of-tanks

So I have an elite Chaffee with crew all 50% camouflage and camo painting and vertical stabilizer + vents and camo net.

But I have some problems playing this tank.

AFAIK I should scout and not shoot. Well this is what happens if I do what people tell me to:

1. **Passive scouting.** so I get to behind a bush and stay still and not shoot. I'll get spotted while I've spotted no one(I don't have sixth sense, but sometimes there's a notification) so I move back and by that time other medium tanks are already gone further then me! so basically there's no need for me
2. **Active scout.** I go show a bit of my hull and comeback, sometimes I do spot people! but most of the times no matter how much I do i'll get 1 hitted by tier VIII or shot in the track and die. I don't dive in, I just do what quicky baby or mighty jingles do, or other people in replays , but somehow they dodge all the bullet, see everybody and no one sees them, but me, I see no one and everybody sees me and I get 1 hit no matter if i'm turning at 72 km/h

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at some training tips / videos for the chaffe?  try looking at the world of tanks forums or wiki.  maybe you're missing something.  I would also recommend looking at some forum posts of good scouting spots on maps, this is usually very helpful as it just helps to give some strategies for how you go about your game.

Comment: I've almost read every single one of them, I've problem with td too, I always get spotted and never know where to go, everybody is always behind ahill or something

Comment: Right, i cant at the moment but i will look into this further for you when i can (it will be this evening when i get back to you) so hang on there!

Comment: ok :( thanks, it's driving me nuts. I can post a replay of one of my games if you would like to :?

Comment: Ok i think I hve some kind of disorder, some games i get every single medal available and 700xp but sometimes i get negative credit and 75 xp :) I'm mostly good on certain maps.! i sometimes get slow for no reason like 40 km/h :( If i could somehow dodge shells while active scouting it would be good, btw I feel like I'm getting better at it!

Comment: @user3033693 don't worry, everyone has bad games. Even QB has battles where he gets nailed by arty and does 250 damage in a Tier 10 battle

Comment: good to know :) @Timpanus

Comment: @user3033693 i'm so sorry I haven't got back to you sooner :(  I have looked on youtube a bit and came up with a supposed series of videos the first episode of which is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_8c1yN_B0A here.   These should give you a base-point to go look for your own tips!

Comment: The [WoT View Range video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qrQ1UPltXg) is excellent if you haven't seen it. In particular see 4:30 for how to hide in bushes, 2:25 for visibility checkpoints, and 3:00 for spotting from behind cover.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're first guess as to how to play the Chaffee well is right. Due to its slow (relatively) top speed for a Tier 5 light tank and to its fantastic (390m base) view range, it should absolutely be played as a passive scout early in the game. The reason you get spotted before you spot enemy targets is your equipment. Since you already have a 50% camouflage crew and camouflage paint applied, you can live without the camo net. Take the camouflage net off and replace it with either Binoculars or Coated optics (to personal taste). This will improve your view range even further, allowing you to spot enemy tanks further off more effectively. You'll have to choose your bushes more carefully in order to ensure staying hidden, but your scouting will be much more effective.

The next major thing to know about the Chaffee (and all lights in general) is when to make your break. At some point later in the game (unless your team is already losing hopelessly), you'll have the opportunity to get moving and circle isolated heavies and Tank Destroyers and kill the enemy arty. At this point, you will use your speed and agility to kill slower moving tanks by avoiding their guns and getting around them. This is where you'll do most of your damage to the enemy. The exact moment when you go from scouting to flanking and cleanup will be different for every battle, so you will have difficulty with this initially but will get better with time. This strategy of scout-then-flank is actually how I got my Ace Tanker and Mark of Excellence on my Chaffee.

A couple more useful tricks:

- Activate minimap view/signal range/draw distance markers. Found in the bottom right corner of the main settings page, this will show you how far your view range actually extends, so you have better perspective on what is or isn't spotted.
- You describe popping around a corner or over a ridge to spot people. This is a great idea and a good way to get spots, but if you keep appearing in the same spot over and over, the enemies will be pre-aimed at that location to hit you. Try to go around different corners of a building, or over a different part of a ridge every time and you'll find you get hit less.
- Work on map awareness. Know where are the best places to scout, to snipe, and to flank on all the maps you play on. it may seem daunting, but you'll get it over time.
- As for Jingles and QB, as I've gotten better at playing WoT I've noticed all the little things you have to do to play well. They may look like they're just yoloing it around a field in their AMX 13 90 or Walker Bulldog, but there are so many complexities that you won't notice until you have the experience playing.

And that's pretty much it. Follow these strategies and you should find that your performance in the Chaffee begins to significantly improve. Not only that, but you'll have more fun, and these strategies will follow you all the way through the American light tanks. The spot/flank strategy is still basically how I play my Walker Bulldog, 2 tiers higher. Seriously though, the Binoculars or Coated Optics should be your first priority. Without those, passive scouting is much harder.

Good luck, and have fun!

Comment: I'm terrible at the third thing you mentioned :) I don't know any spots, I don't know maps, there are many places in many maps that i haven't ever been :S

Comment: btw, I've already bought the next tank but not used it does it have a similar playstyle :?

Comment: @user3033693 yup. All American lights have that basic playstyle

Comment: @user3033693 you mentioned: "I don't know any spots, I don't know maps" I really think this is most of your problem.  I have, further to my above comment on your question, found a specific video for the Chaffee: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIsizL6MKDk

Answer (score 2):

Some more important things to remember, when learning with light tanks. In addtion, what was already said:

Don't be too eager. Your priority is to stay alive and light tanks have much more difficult life in this. Start to play more like a coward before you get knowledge of map. Than you can start risk more. Always remember: dead scout does not spot anything.

Don't fight! Unless you are acompanied with your team mates. Even with other light tanks, if not necessary. They can damage you badly even when you win. Once situation starts to get bad, don't be a hero and just get the hell out.

More suggestions to learn:

- study, how spotting algorithm in WoT technically works. This will help you to cover more effectively
- Remember that you are visible 5 seconds (approximately) from moment you get back into cover. Get from cover - spot enemy and get spotted yourself meanwhile
- hide - wait 5 seconds to get camo again. Repeat 2-3 times, then relax and wait until there is not so much heat on you. Or even better - find a new place.
- Use autospotting of tanks, which are closer than 50m, even when they are behind obstacle and you don't have direct view.

Light tanks are far most difficult class to play. Don't be upset you got killed. Use your head. Analyze your game and learn from your mistakes. Be patient.